# Need help on error: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.1.RELEASE:run

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Im trying to run this project which uses kafka. However I keep running into this error while trying to use mvn spring-boot:run

Below is the full pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.1.RELEASE
 

Sherpa
Module
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Module
Sherpa Module 1 to build a real time stream processing

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any suggestions to fix this are welcome.

Comment: Do you have a class with `@SpringBootApplication` ?

Comment: Yes,  I do have a class with springboot application, I was able to fix this problem now. It was caused by @RESTCONTROLLER and how I was implementing it.